# Sync Framework : How to specify the sync order of multiple tables?

Tags: frameworks, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

Does anynody know a way to sync multiple tables in a particular order. in detail, there are new created data in both parent and child tables and it requires the parent-insertion happens before the child does.

Answer (score 3):

The order in which each table is processed depends on the order in which its `SyncTable` object was added to the collection of tables for the synchronization agent.

The following table adds the customer table before the order table.

```
SyncGroup customerOrderSyncGroup = new SyncGroup("CustomerOrder");

SyncTable customerSyncTable = new SyncTable("Customer");
customerSyncTable.CreationOption = TableCreationOption.DropExistingOrCreateNewTable;
customerSyncTable.SyncDirection = SyncDirection.DownloadOnly;
customerSyncTable.SyncGroup = customerOrderSyncGroup;
this.Configuration.SyncTables.Add(customerSyncTable);

SyncTable orderSyncTable = new SyncTable("Order");
orderSyncTable.CreationOption = TableCreationOption.DropExistingOrCreateNewTable;
orderSyncTable.SyncDirection = SyncDirection.DownloadOnly;
orderSyncTable.SyncGroup = customerOrderSyncGroup;
this.Configuration.SyncTables.Add(orderSyncTable);
```

More information is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902828.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you have master detail records, such as order and orderdetail, then please JUST the tables that are related into their own sync group, (create other sync groups for other unreleated tables) then sync that group inside a transaction. This ensures that both master and detail records get synchd or neither do.

Shout if you need more on how to do this..

Comment: Did this answer your problem? Can I help more?